# Uploading and Downloading Files on linux hosting server Using RSync algorithm

Tags: java, linux, hosting, rsync

i am writing an application in java that takes backup of files on server.It is a windows version application. In my application i have to perform incremental backup operation. For implementing incremental backup i am trying to follow rsync algorithm. i got one lib in java "jarsync0.3" but not getting how to write a code using rsync for uploading and downloading files on linux hosting server (SSH enabled).

I searched enough to get any solution which will help me for uploading and downloading files using rsync, but could not succeeded.

Please give me your valuable suggestion that will help me to get a way for using rsync for files uploading and downloading on linux hosting server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, it is not quite clear if you are trying to:

- implement rsync client
- implement rsync server
- or just use rsync internal algorithms for some other purpose

For first two options: forget about it :-) See ["Any good rsync library for Java?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246255/any-good-rsync-library-for-java) for details.

If you need the last option - well, good luck. [Wikipedia is your friend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i am implementing rsync client but it seems like system calls (implementing through system commands) is only better option for implementing rsync.